# i have a MLM system. where User hasmany Users. now i want to get all users of root/ node A user. where one user hasmany user (in deep) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship, mlm

i have a MLM system. where User hasmany Users. now i want to get all users of root/ lavel-1 user and where one user hasmany user and each of the users can hasmany user (in deep) laravel.

Here Is relation in model:

```php
    //    All Child Refer
    public function referral_child_users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'ref_by', 'id')->select('id', 'username', 'ref_by');[!
    }

    //    All Child Refer
    public function referral_multilevel_child_users()
    {
        return $this->referral_child_users()
        ->with('referral_multilevel_child_users');
    }
```

in Controller:

```php
$user = User::with('referral_multilevel_child_users')->select('id', 'username', 'ref_by')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

then i got an error: `Undefined array key 0`

for example: i want all count of users whose prime parent is A

[image]

Comment: Where did the error come from? Have you confirmed your relationship is actually working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the with function `->with(['referral_multilevel_child_users']);`

```php
    //    All Child Refer
    public function referral_multilevel_child_users()
    {
        return $this->referral_child_users()
        ->with(['referral_multilevel_child_users']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way you use the query to fetch data cause the result

Check this out:

```php
$user = \Auth::user();
        $users = User::where('ref_by', $user->id)
            ->orWhereHas('referral_multilevel_child_users', function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('ref_by', $user->id);
            })
            ->get();
```